# Integrating data into existing SSAS tabular model

Tags: sql, powerbi, ssas-tabular

I have a tabular model setup in SSAS (star schema). The existing data is all from one system and i have setup a summary table based on the fact tables, i.e Total Sales, Sales MTD, Sales YTD, etc.

I now have to integrate another dataset from an additional system into this model. These datasets have one field in common, an ID field (that is used as the grouping ID in my summary table). This new data set will include sales $, so i need to include these in my summary table.I would like to keep my model structure the same, along with the summary table. How could i seamlessly integrate this data?

Comment: The way I see it, it is a data model problem. If working with SSAS +2017 you may merge the datasets on Power Query steps in the Table Properties like edit query in Power Bi.
If you can't because you have an old version, you may need to add it as a new source in star schema and integrate it as a fact. Then use measures to help the results between them.